# PostgreSQL Full Text Search, short query

Tags: database, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table here called suggestions where I store many search terms to suggest to a user in an autocomplete feature.

I'm using [PostgreSQL Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) but the problem is that I need the query to work with only 3 chars. For example, if the user wanna search for iPhone 6, when he type iph all iphone suggestions must appear. But the query only works when the user types iPhone.

And this happens to all words... the biggest the word is the more the user needs to type.

This is the query I'm using:

```html
SELECT a.word 
FROM public.auto_complete a
WHERE to_tsvector(a.word) @@ to_tsquery('iph')
ORDER BY a.word
LIMIT 5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `to_tsquery('iph:*')`

Comment: It worked the way i wanted! Thank you my friend!